# p value of slicing

Tags: statistics

Here is the problem, in the population of size 3635, 41% of population(1490) are non-book readers($N$), and the rest 59%(2145) are book readers($R$).

I slice the population using employment status. 
Among the population, 2266 are unemployed and 1369 are employed.

Among those unemployed, 952 are $N$ and 1314 are $R$.

Among those employed, 538 are $N$ and 831 are $R$.

And the research paper says the $p$ value of such distribution is $0.11$. I have no idea how they arrived at this. Any enlightenment?

Comment: The p value for what test? A p value does not really make sense without a test.

Comment: I would suppose the test for Non-book readers and book readers. The full report can be assessed here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r95hd0bererrjw9/1-s2.0-S0277953616303689-main.pdf?dl=0 and the table I was talking about is on the 2nd page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They probably used a $\chi^2$-test.

For example the following R code gives that $p$ value

```
> chisq.test(matrix(c(952,1314,538,831), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2))

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  matrix(c(952, 1314, 538, 831), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2)
X-squared = 2.4871, df = 1, p-value = 0.1148
```